# Is there a way to access the lowered C# AST in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am writing a [tool](https://cecilifier.me) that, given a (compileable) piece of C# code, generates another source, that using `Mono.Cecil`, outputs an assembly that is *equivalent* to the one produced by compiling the original piece of code. This is achieved by parsing the C# code and visiting the resulting AST and generating calls to the equivalent `Mono.Cecil` APIs (I guess this is somewhat similar to what the code generation part of Roslyn does, but generating calls to `Mono.Cecil` instead of `IL`).

Given that, processing the *lowered version of a given AST* would make the code easier to implement, more robust, etc but looking into the Roslyn sources it does not look like there's a way to access it.

In the best case my code would need to call into the various types in charge of doing the lowering in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering which, AFAICS, are all internal.

Whence the question: is it really not possible to get the *lowered version of a given AST* ?

Comment: I wonder how [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/) does it? The source for it is stored on [GitHub](https://github.com/ashmind/SharpLab). Might be worth looking at.

Comment: AFAICS they use ICSharpCode.Decompiler (https://github.com/ashmind/SharpLab/blob/main/source/Server/Decompilation/CSharpDecompiler.cs). Unfortunately that does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest thing we have that is somewhat "lowered" is our IOperation APIs which are a bit lower level than the syntax/semantic APIs. We don't have an API to give you the fully lowered representation.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a little more explicit about what I am trying to achieve (just keep in mind that I am not a compiler dev :) so my understanding/expectations may be completely off ); what I was expecting was to have some way to, given an AST, get a completely lowered version of it (not even sure if this is technically possible or not). WRT `IOperation` APIs, this is the first time I hear about it but a quick look does not look promising (anyway, I'll take a deeper look later)

Comment: And updated answer, we don't have a way to give you the fully lowered representation although at that point if your Mono.Cecil output is looking at opcodes...just do the emit and then decompile.

Comment: My tool is not looking at *outputed IL*.. it is deriving which *Mono.Cecil* API calls should be emitted to generate the equivalent IL as the C# compiler would produce. My desire to use the lowered AST was to simplify/support handling of features like Async, Iterator blocks, etc